# Can I see a list of location notifications set up through Find my Friends?

Tags: ios, notifications, geolocation, icloud

I want to know if I have already setup a repeating location (geofence) notification in the Find my Friends app before I create a dupe of an old one. Is there a way to see a list of location notifications in the Find my Friends app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap on 'Me' at the bottom of the app then tap the **Notify Friends** button to see a list of your location notifications.

This related Apple support seems to be out of date (for iOS 9 at least) because it says to tap 'Notifications' instead of 'Notify Friends'.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19434?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Just a clarification: tap on the word 'Me' or to the right of it. If you tap the image/icon for you it will take you to the contacts app.